# using d3 maps in angular but while using d3.json url i am getting request error

Tags: angular, d3.js

getting error in unit test angular
node_modules/@types/d3-request/index.d.ts:274:80
274 export function json<ParsedObject extends { [key: string]: any }>(url: string, callback: (this: Request, error: any, d: ParsedObject) => void): Request;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
An argument for 'callback' was not provided.

below is my code

d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson').then((data: GeoJSON) => {

I have tried passing call back function

```
 d3.json<GeoJSON>('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson').then((data: GeoJSON) => {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('fill', '#DBD4B4')
    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);


}).catch((error:any) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.